# Symfony entity set array as single entity elements

Tags: arrays, collections, entity, symfony

i have problem, i would to add prototype array to database but this show me this error:

> Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Tag", "array" given
>
> ...
>
> Post ->setTag (array(array('value' => 'test'), array('value' => 'tess')))

here is my setter for tag:

```
public function setTag(\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tag = null)
{
    $this->tag = $tag;

    return $this;
}
```

I Have two entities with relation, here relation:

```
class Post
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="post")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tag;

    public function setTag(\AppBundle\Entity\Tag $tag = null)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and tag:

```
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="tag")
     */
    private $post;
}
```

Source:

> http://snipet.co.uk/kR
>
> http://snipet.co.uk/gcf
>
> http://snipet.co.uk/0VI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to model a bidirectional many-to-many relation between Post and Tag.

So, first of all, your getters need to return a collection of objects, and your setters need to accept a collection of objects - not only one single object as in your code (your setTag method accepts a parameter of type Tag - but you need an array-like parameter).

Secondly, the Doctrine framework does not work with simple PHP arrays, but with implementations of \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection.

Next, you need to initialize your collection fields in the constructors of your entity classes with an implementation of the Collection class - you can use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.

So your entity classes should look rather like this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Post
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="posts")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posts_tags")
    */
    private $tags;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    public function setTags(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;
    }
}


/**
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Tag
{
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="tags")
    */
    private $posts;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->posts = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getPosts()
    {
        return $this->posts;
    }

    public function setPosts(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $posts)
    {
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }

}
```

I strongly advise you to read once again the documentation of the Doctrine framework, how to annotate your entities, and how to model relations: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: ok i changed my code here is current, i make it with your tips. http://snipet.co.uk/qXZ/raw But always on submit from i see message:
"Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\Tag", "string" given"
Maybe my controller is bad?

Comment: Yes, something calls your addTag or removeTag methods with a parameter of wrong type. If my answer above was helpful to you, could you please upvote it (the upwards arrow button next to it)? Thank you